# GCP console user is asking password to change as root user

Tags: google-compute-engine

I m using GCP compute engine, i m validated through my gmail account to access the instance. 
On login to the compute engine instance , i can able to change it to user . This is the usual process which i do for last 2 years .

Suddently today while i m trying to change the user to root from my user(gmail authenticated user) it is asking password for my user .

In ssh key adding page it is marked as :

```
ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 AAAAE2VjZHNhLXNoYTIt…","expireOn":"2018-10-01T14:39:09+0000"}
```

How to overcome this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by enabling OS Login. The login prompt has been bugging me about that for a while now. I guess they made it mandatory and didn't tell anyone.